# How to do this via mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

http://mydomain.com/bubba

goes to
http://mydomain.com/myscript.php?name=bubba

But does not match anything with an extension on it (.php, .html, etc).

I've been working on this for the last several hours and I cannot see how to do it.  Every piece of documentation I find specifically doesn't work.

I'm doing this on a shared host (1and1.com) with .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrites every non-existant file to `myscript.php?name=requested`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ myscript.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `RewriteCond -f`, to check whether the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

To only match things without a period:

```
^([^.]+)$ myscript.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```